List all user's of all group of all sub_sites
I search help about a pws script on sharepoint 2019 (not Sharepoint online)
I want to list all sub-sites of a collection with all the groups associated (with kind of the groups) and all members in each groups.
It should be something like this :
try
 {
  ##variables
  ##
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
  $sites = get-spsite -limit All
  foreach($site in $sites) 
  {
    foreach($sitegroup in $site.RootWeb.SiteGroups) 
    {
        foreach($user in $sitegroup.Users)
        {
        "$($site.url) `t $($sitegroup.Name) `t $($user.displayname) `t $($user)" | out-file result.csv -append
        }
   }
}



 }
 ##Error's Management
 catch
{
}
finally
{
}

But, that doesn't displayed all group of the subsite and the kind of group (Read, design, edit, contribute, full control)
if someone could help directly with the script or guid me if i have to use another sharepoint cmdlet. I try to get it with spuser
thanks a lot

Are you only looking for groups? What about users granted access directly?
